# Why am I not getting List Object from controller to ajax and getting 406 error?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using

- java-7
- apache-7 server

#### APIs:

- Spring 4.0.1 jar
- jackson-core -2.6.3 jar
- jackson-mapper-asl jar
- jacksonall-1.9.0 jar
- jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar.

#### Code:

```
 function doAjaxPost() {    
 var user= { 
 nameA: $('#name').val(), 
 emailA: $('#email').val(),
  
 };

 $.ajax({
 type : "post", 
 url: "hello.htm",
 data: JSON.stringify(user),
 contentType: 'application/json',

 success : function(response) {
 alert(response); 
 },
 error : function(e) {
 alert('Error: ' + e); 
 }
 });
 }


 // controller

 @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)

 public @ResponseBody List<String> hello11(@RequestBody UserBean user)
 {
  System.out.println(user.getEmailA());

  List<String> listObj=new ArrayList<String>();
  listObj.add("jay mata dee");
 
  return listObj;

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add more description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

change url in your ajax as below and try...

url: "hello",

Comment: No need to change "hello" becoz, It's going inside controller and working fine. BUT at returning(List Object) time giving problem.

Comment: Mr @Ravi Chand. plz give me solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the MessageConverter in your Configuration. Spring have to know how to create a requested **application/json** `@ResponseBody`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    [...]

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

}
```

Also you need to include some mapping libraries:

pom.xml

```
<!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```